Estimate the exponential order of a non-continuously-differentiable function with integral inequalities
Suppose $V(x(t))$ is not continuously differentiable. There is a conclusion: If $V(x(t))$ holds
$$V(x(t))-V(x(t_{0}))\leq-\lambda\int_{t_0}^{t}V(x(s)) ds,$$
then
$$V(x(t))\leq e^{-\lambda(t-t_{0})}V(x(t_{0})),$$
where $t$ is variable, $t_{0}$ is a constant.
This conclusion comes from a paper regarding control theory Model predictive control of switched nonlinear systems under average dwell-time.
Since $V(x(t))$ is not continuously differentiable, we cannot take the derivative of both sides of the equation. I try to integrate both sides from $t_{0}$ to $t$, however, the obtained double integral is still hard to transform into a form with respect to $e^{\lambda t}$.

In order to be integrable, V has to be absolute continuous, that is in the intervall $$x,x+dx$$ it has at most a finite discrete set of summable step discontinuities. Over a single step the integral has a linear approximation with a kink. So you can say that
$$\begin {align} 
 &V (x (t)) < V\left (x\left (t_ 0 \right) \right) - \lambda  \int_ 0^t
   V (x (s)) \, ds \\
 &V (x (\text {dt} + t)) < V (x (t)) - \lambda  \int_t^{\text {dt} + t} V (x (s))
   \, ds \\
  &(1+\text {dt}\  \lambda )\  V (x (\text {dt} + t)) < (1 - \text {dt}\  \lambda ) \   V (x (t)) \\
 &V (x (\text {dt} + t)) < \frac {1 - \text {dt} \ \lambda 
      } {1+\text {dt} \ \lambda }\  V (x (t)) < V (x (t)) \\
\end {align}$$
meaning that the solution is dominated by the solution of a linear ODE $V' = -\lambda \ V $with negative slope

Thank you for your valuable answer. Following your line, we have $$V(x(t+dt))\leq V(x(t))-\lambda dtV(t).$$ It follows that $$V(x(t+dt))-V(x(t))\leq -\lambda dtV(t),$$ which seems equivalent to $V'\leq -\lambda V.$ However, how we can obtain $$V(x(t))\leq e^{-\lambda (t-t_0)}V(x(t_0))$$ rigorously?
